# trimmed/winsorized standard deviation

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, python-3.x, scipy

What's an efficient way to calculate a [trimmed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimmed_estimator) or [winsorized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsorising) standard deviation of a list?

I don't mind using `numpy`, but if I have to make a separate copy of the list, it's going to be quite slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make two copies, but you should give it a try because it should be very fast.

```
def trimmed_std(data, low, high):
    tmp = np.asarray(data)
    return tmp[(low <= tmp) & (tmp < high)].std()
```

Do you need to do rank order trimming (ie 5% trimmed)?

Update:

If you need percentile trimming, the best way I can think of is to sort the data first. Something like this should work:

```
def trimmed_std(data, percentile):
    data = np.array(data)
    data.sort()
    percentile = percentile / 2.
    low = int(percentile * len(data))
    high = int((1. - percentile) * len(data))
    return data[low:high].std(ddof=0)
```

You can obviously implement this without using numpy, but even including the time of converting the list to an array, using numpy is faster than anything I could think of.

Comment: Yes, I need to do rank order (percentile) trimming. That's why I was particularly concerned with the time: I need to pass once more just to determine which values of the original list to keep.

Answer (score 1):

This is what generator functions are for.

SD requires two passes, plus a count.  For this reason, you'll need to "tee" some iterators over the base collection.

So.

```
trimmed = ( x for x in the_list if low <= x < high )
sum_iter, len_iter, var_iter = itertools.tee( trimmed, 3 )
n = sum( 1 for x in len_iter)
mean = sum( sum_iter ) / n
sd = math.sqrt( sum( (x-mean)**2 for x in var_iter ) / (n-1) )
```

Something like that might do what you want without copying anything.

Comment: It does, but somehow it is 8 times slower than copying to numpy array :( I suppose the regular python overhead slows things down much more than a copy...

Comment: 8 times slower!  That shows the value of `numpy` pretty starkly.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get an unbiased trimmed mean you have to account for fractional bits of items in the list as described [here](http://www.fordham.edu/economics/vinod/st1trim.doc) and (a little less directly) [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4252/how-to-calculate-the-truncated-or-trimmed-mean/). I wrote a function to do it:

```
def percent_tmean( data, pcent ):
   # make sure data is a list
   dc = list( data )
   # find the number of items
   n = len(dc)
   # sort the list
   dc.sort()
   # get the proportion to trim
   p = pcent / 100.0
   k = n*p
   # print "n = %i\np = %.3f\nk = %.3f" % ( n,p,k )
   # get the decimal and integer parts of k
   dec_part, int_part = modf( k )
   # get an index we can use
   index = int(int_part)
   # trim down the list
   dc = dc[ index: index * -1 ]
   # deal with the case of trimming fractional items
   if dec_part != 0.0:
       # deal with the first remaining item
       dc[ 0 ] = dc[ 0 ] * (1 - dec_part)
       # deal with last remaining item
       dc[ -1 ] = dc[ -1 ] * (1 - dec_part)
   return sum( dc ) / ( n - 2.0*k )
```

I also made [an iPython Notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/5874219) that demonstrates it.

My function will probably be slower than those already posted but it will give unbiased results.